# Using Symfony voters on collectionOperations (GET)

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I want to use symfony voters in API PLATFORM. I don't have any problem when I use it on `itempsOperations` (GET, PUT, DELETE), but when I use it in `collectionOperations` especially in GET (POST works well), I cannot access to the $subject because in GET operation API PLATFORM returns an instance of "ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Paginator" and not entity object.

```
* @ApiResource(
*         collectionOperations={
*              "GET"={
*                   "access_control"="is_granted('GET', object)",
*               },
*               "POST"={
*                   "access_control"="is_granted('ADD', object)",
*                }
*         }
* )
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem, dont know if this is a feature or a bug. Since we're basically asking for a set of this recources. And with that in mind a pagination object would make sense, I guess.

A solution arround this issue could be the following:

---

```
@\Entity\YourEntity.php

* @ApiResource(
*         collectionOperations={
*              "GET"={
*                   "access_control"="is_granted('GET', _api_resource_class)",
*               },
*         }
* )
```

---

```
@\Security\Voter\YourVoter.php
/**
 * Determines if the attribute and subject are supported by this voter.
 *
 * @param string $attribute An attribute
 * @param mixed  $subject   The subject to secure, e.g. an object the user wants to access or any other PHP type
 *
 * @return bool True if the attribute and subject are supported, false otherwise
 */
protected function supports($attribute, $subject)
{


    // If the subject is a string check if class exists to support collectionOperations
    if(is_string($subject) && class_exists($subject)) {
        $subject = new $subject;
    }

    if(in_array($attribute, ['GET'])
        && $subject instanceof YourEntity) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Does it allowed to access method like $book->getOwener() ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token)` and check if the subject is an instanceof Book, if so you can call the $subject->getOwner()